# In c++ 11, how to invoke an arbitrary callable object?

Tags: c++, callable

The concept of callable is defined in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable.

Suppose I have a callable object **f** that has one argument of type **T*** and return type **void**. **f** can be any callable type (a function object, a pointer to member function, a pointer to data member, etc). How can I invoke **f**?

Simply calling f(x) fails since f can be a pointer to member function or data member. Is there a simple way to call **f**? One possible solution is std::bind(f, x)(), but this solution becomes more complex when **f** has more arguments.

Comment: Do you have a use case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what `std::invoke` does, but it won't be standard until C++17.  You can make your own version, but it can be pretty complicated if it is fully general.

Here's the basic idea for two cases (code taken from cppreference.com):

```
template <class F, class... Args>
inline auto INVOKE(F&& f, Args&&... args) ->
    decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Base, class T, class Derived>
inline auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmd, Derived&& ref) ->
    decltype(std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd) {
      return std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd;
}
```

Comment: Is it implemented in gcc 5.2?

Comment: I think I can just copy the possible implementation provided in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke . Thanks.

Comment: For the record, apparently MSVC2015 has its full implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than implementing `INVOKE` yourself, use one of the [library features that uses it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable#Standard_library). In particular, [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()) works. Thus you can have the effect of `std::invoke(f, args...)` with `std::ref(f)(args...)`:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto invoke(F f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::ref(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return std::ref(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I didn't forward `f` because `std::reference_wrapper` requires that the object passed in is not an rvalue. Using `std::bind` instead of `std::ref` doesn't fix the problem. What this means is that for a function object like this:

```
struct F
{
    void operator()() && {
        std::cout << "Rvalue\n";
    }
    void operator()() const& {
        std::cout << "Lvalue\n";
    }
};
```

`invoke(F{})` will print `Lvalue`, whereas `std::invoke(F{})` in C++17 would print `Rvalue`.

<sub>I found the technique from [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0312r1.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boost::hof::apply`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/apply.html):

```
#include <boost/hof/apply.hpp>

// ...
boost::hof::apply(f, args...);
```

`boost::hof::apply` performs the same operation that [`INVOKE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) does.

---

Alternatively, use [`boost::hana::apply`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga30027c383676084be151ef3c6cf2829f), which does the same thing