# Template function which takes lambda with variadic parameters

Tags: c++11, lambda, template-function

Educational task: want to write a function which take functional object and its arguments and call it using perfect forwarding:

```
auto fun = [](std::string a, std::string const& b) { return a += b; };
std::string s("world!");
s = apply(fun, std::string("Hello, "), s);
```

Had written the function:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
T apply(std::function<T(Args...)>&& fun, Args&& ... args)
{
    return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

However got error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘apply(main()::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string, const string&)>&, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string&)’
    s = apply(fun, std::string("Hello, "), s);
                                            ^
candidate: template<class T, class ... Args> T&& apply(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>, Args&& ...)
T apply(std::function<T(Args...)> fun, Args&& ... args)
    ^~~~~

note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:

note: ‘main()::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string, const string&)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’

s = apply(fun, std::string("Hello, "), s);
```

What is wrong with syntax? How to fix?

Comment: `fun` is not an instance of `std::function`. You could do `apply(std::function<void(std::string, std::string const&)>(fun), ...)`, or you could have `apply` take an arbitrary functional, not `std::function` specifically - at which point you'll reinvent [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik std::function is not a requirement. Could You provide and answer without it please?

Comment: Like I said - look at `std::invoke`. Your `apply` tries to do the same thing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik have some problem with `decltype(auto)`: error: expected primary-expression before ‘auto’: 
 decltype(auto) apply(F&& fun, Args&&... args)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918679/in-c-11-how-to-invoke-an-arbitrary-callable-object

Comment: @IgorTandetnik works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without `std::function`:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Args>
auto apply(F&& fun, Args&&... args) ->
    decltype(std::forward<F>(fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```