# Template Specialization With Callable Argument Not Working As Expected

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code complains on the line with `dp1` "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments".  I expect that dp1 would match the `IsInstantiation` specialization of `Dispatch`, but it errors.

How would I change this code so that it will work as I expect?  I am using VS2015 and cannot use `std::invoke` or `std::is_invokable`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
class TemplateA {};

struct Callable
{
    void operator()() {};
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr auto Invoke(F &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    return f(std::forward(args)...);
}

template <template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct IsInstantiation : std::false_type {};

template <template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct IsInstantiation<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename = void>
struct HasNoArgs : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasNoArgs<T, std::void_t<decltype(Invoke(T{}))>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T1, typename = void>
class Dispatch;

template <typename T1>
class Dispatch<T1, std::enable_if_t<HasNoArgs<T1>::value>> {};

template <typename T1>
class Dispatch<T1, std::enable_if_t<IsInstantiation<TemplateA, T1>::value>> {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Dispatch<TemplateA<int>> dp1;
    Dispatch<Callable> dp2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: using INVOKE in C++11: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32918679/1896169

Comment: I'd rename `HasNoArgs` to be `CanInvokeWithNoArgs` because you are asking two questions, 1. can we call `Invoke` at all for the type? and 2. can we do it with no arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. This is an improper use of `forward`:

   ```
   return f(std::forward(args)...);
   ```

   The function parameter for `std::forward` is a non-deduced context, on purpose. So this call will never succeed. You want `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`
2. `Invoke` is SFINAE unfriendly:

   ```
   template <typename F, typename... Args>
   constexpr auto Invoke(F &&f, Args &&... args)
   { ... }
   ```

   If `F` is indeed invocable with `Args...`, this function will work fine. If it isn't, then this is a hard compile error because the problem only surfaces in the *body*, which is outside of the "immediate context" of the substitution. As a result, it's not a "substitution failure" (the SF in SFINAE), it's an instantiation failure. In `HasNoArgs`, you're trying to see if you can invoke it - which means you need a substitution failure. To do that, you need to lift the expression into the immediate context:

   ```
   template <typename F, typename... Args>
   constexpr auto Invoke(F &&f, Args &&... args)
       -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
   { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
   ```

   Now, it's SFINAE friendly (and additionally, can return a reference).
3. Your `HasNoArgs` checks more than you think it does:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct HasNoArgs<T, std::void_t<decltype(Invoke(T{}))>> : std::true_type {};
   ```

   This requires that `T` can be invoked with no arguments, which after fixing #1 and #2 above, is now possible. But it *also* requires that `T{}` be a valid expression. Non-default-constructible callables will fail this test, but not for the reason that the test claims it's looking for. To fix that, use `std::declval`:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct HasNoArgs<T, std::void_t<decltype(Invoke(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};
   ```

Comment: I'd probably write `std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` so that it'd call the appropriate ref-qualified `operator()` overload.

Comment: I usually have the template argument on `std::forward`, I just forgot it here and the compiler didn't catch it.  I had used `std::declval` for exactly that reason on an earlier version, but forgot why when I wrote this simple example.